# Create users with only view privilege in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am the administartor of TeamCity 9.0 which is my continuous integration server. I have added many users for different projects. They have the permission to manually trigger the build, but they cannot edit the configurations.

Now , I need to add a user so that the user can view the Web UI and get the logs etc ; but he must not be able to trigger the build. In short, the run button in the Web UI should not work for that user or should be invisible. How can I achieve that? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **Administration** on top right corner. Under **User Management** on left side of the UI, click on **Users**. Click on the user you want. Under **Roles** tab select **Assign Role**. In the pop up select what privilege you want to give to that user for what project.

Check this link https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Role+and+Permission for knowing about different types of users in TeamCity.

Answer (score 2):

In the default installation, the `All Users` group only has the `Project viewer` role associated with it, which only has the `View project and all parent projects` permission. You'll see the `Project developer` role by default has the `Run build` and `Stop build` permissions, and many more.

What does your permission set up look like, i.e. what group is the user assigned to and what roles are associated with that group.

You can get a sort of "effective permissions" overview for a user on the "Roles" tab of a user, this shows how the user is getting permission for which projects via the groups they are in.

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity provides a [built-in role](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Role+and+Permission), Project Viewer, that grants users read-only access to projects. You can also create your own roles with permissions tailored for your team. See *Administration* > *User Management* > *Roles*.